# 360 pano renders appear tilted

Tags: panoramic

I'm trying to export 360 pano images and animations from Blender. If I rotate the Z axis of my camera in blender, I can rotate it all the way around as I were standing in one place and turning-all the vertical lines remain vertical. When I view the exported equirectangular images in Adobe Premier's VR viewer or on Youtube as a 360 video however, then drag the view directly sideways, the verticals appear dramatically tilted.

Rendering with Cycles, to target resolution of 3840x1920. Camera settings Pano, Equirectangular. Importing into Premier correctly identifies images or video as Monoscopic Equirectangular, Captured View: 360° Horizontal by 180° Vertical.

Am I misunderstanding how this SHOULD appear in a 360 viewer or doing something incorrectly?

pic 1: Blender showing main camera view
pic 2: Blender with camera Z rotated to left
pic 3: 360 on youtube after dragging view directly to the left

[image: Blender with main camera view]

[image: Blender with camera Z rotated to left]

[image: View on youtube after dragging view directly to left]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this issue, it would seem you cannot animate a Blender camera for youtube 360 as you might when creating a regular animation, by simply moving the camera. If the camera is anywhere but in the center of the Blender world, the panoramic image rendered will be distorted in relation to that camera. The only way I found that worked is to leave the camera fixed at 0, 0 in Blender, and move the entire scene in relation to that fixed camera. I would love to have some clarification from someone here who understands better than I.